# Designing Database

Tags: html, database-design

I need to design database with frontend as HTML.
This is my first attempt to do this. 
What I need is, 
- User can input a word from HTML page, click submit
  I will query the word to get a URL from database and user sees that webpage(pointed by URL).
Just enter word, submit and get the webpage displayed.

People suggested using JSP/Access. I am new to everything. 
Can you please point out what exactly I need to do?

Thanks a ton.

Comment: Are you completely new, like, never wrote a single line of HTML or...?

Comment: No.. I have written HTML code before.. just that I am completely new to JSP/PHP and all.. and people are suggesting me to use them to connect to database and query into it.. whenever user enters any word.. I wanted to know how to do that..

Answer (score 1):

Following is the way you need to approach
Step1: 
Create an HTML page which can take an input from the users

Step 2:
After getting the data from the user, create a connection to the database and pass the searched string as an input paramater.

Step 3:
You will get a result set from a database

Step 4:
Iterate through the result set and display in the html page, if you require the url to be given for those url, so when user clicks So that he will be directed to those websites.

Sample Query:

Select * from table1 where url_Word like '%Search_String'

This will be the procedure that you need to follow to complete your work.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need a database you need a text file.  If this is a school project you need more information.